# Toggle switch with MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I have a view with a table, each row I have a "+" sign, when I click "+", it will show the detail of that row. And now, I try to toggle this "+" to "-" after clicking, and when I click "-", it will hide the detail of this row, and I am stuck with this. Below is my View

```
@Html.Grid(Model.Nodes).Sort(sortOptions).Columns(x=>
    {            
        x.For(c => string.Format("<a class='expander' style='color:black;text-decoration:none;' href='showDetail'>" + "{0}" + "</a>", (c.ChildrenCount > 0 && c.EntityType == "TextNode") ? "+" : "")).DoNotEncode();       
    }).Attributes(Class => "DetailTable").Empty("No data.")

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".expander").click(function () {

        //implementation here

        });

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem as follow:

- created a toggleState function for the onclick event
- $(document).on

  function toggleState(item) {

  ```
  if (item.className == "expander") {
      item.className = "expanderOff";
  } else {
      item.className = "expander";
  }
  ```

  }

  $(document).on("click", ".expander", function () {

  });

  $(document).on("click", ".expanderOff", function () {

  });

And it's done. :)

Comment: You could use .toggleClass() for cleaner code. http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/